# Get jsonArray objects without value name and pass it to list

Tags: android, json, for-loop, arraylist

I am trying to read json array without object name, and pass it to a list.

My json looks like :

```
"facilites": [
    "Pool",
    " Air Conditioning",
    " Pets Allowed",
    " Fitness center",
    " Kitchen",
    " Internet",
    " Sona"
  ]
```

I am trying to retrieve it using the following code -

```
for (int l = 0; l < chaletFacilities.length(); l++){
                            String facilities =  chaletFacilities.getString(l);
                            list = new ArrayList<String>();
                            list.add(facilities);

                        }
```

Inside the main loop I put to my pojo class `chalets.setList(list);`

The issue is in this line `list.add(facilities);` it only add the last element. After looping through all, list  carry `sona` only.

Comment: this is not valid json please check here https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: check below answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list should be instantiated outside the loop.

```
list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int l = 0; l < chaletFacilities.length(); l++){
  String facilities =  chaletFacilities.getString(l);
  list.add(facilities);
}
```

An improvement would be directly add string to list instead of capturing it into a string variable like `list.add(chaletFacilities.getString(l))`

Comment: System said after 3 mint.

Answer (score 1):

Move initialization of your `ArrayList` outside of your loop.
Do like this

```
list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int l = 0; l < chaletFacilities.length(); l++){
       list.add(chaletFacilities.getString(l))
}
```

What you doing is initializing yourlist again and again and adding the element. So while last iteration the list is getting initialized again and   only single element is being added to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int l = 0; l < chaletFacilities.length(); l++){
           String facilities =  chaletFacilities.getString(l);
           list.add(facilities);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the new list always. So your list size will be 1 with the last value in chaletFacilities array.

Solution: Keep your list initialization outside the for loop as below, and add all the values under the array into single list you created in the top.

```
list = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int l = 0; l < chaletFacilities.length(); l++)
 {
list.add(chaletFacilities.getString(l));
 }
```